How I could handle the Bad Request error for Post Graphql?
I have a test case by Ropot frame work but I have to Post graphql but I faced this Error:
enter image description here
My Robot Keyword is
     ${orderid}  Get Order ID
     ${headers}  Create Dictionary
    ...  X-Shopify-Access-Token    shppa_some_hexadecimal_hash
    ...  Content-Type    application/json
    ${body}  Create dictionary
    ...   query= "query": {"tag:"_wc_order_id:${orderid}""}
    Create Session  shopifysession  ${Shopify_BaseURL_Staging}  disable_warnings=1
    ${response}  RequestsLibrary.POST On Session  shopifysession  admin/api/2023-04/graphql
    ...  headers=${headers}  data=${body}
    Status Should Be  200  ${response.json()}

    ${response_body}  Evaluate  json.loads(r'''${response.content}''')
    Log  ${response_body}

The Query is :
query DraftOrders {
    draftOrders(first: 5, query: "tag:'_wc_order_id:2398647'") {
        nodes {
            email
            id
            subtotalPrice
            tags
            totalPrice
            totalShippingPrice
            totalTax
            
        }
    }
}


